# jsonpath find string value in the jsonarray independent of array index

Tags: arrays, json, scala, gatling, jsonpath

I have a Gatling JSON objects of array. The object contains error messages e.g.

```
"error": [
    {
      "errorCode": "111",
      "errorMessage": "very dynamic error :- at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5d0edb12; line: 6, column: 6]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: "
    },
    {
      "errorCode": null,
      "errorMessage": "Fixed Error Message"
    },
    {
      "errorCode": "112",
      "errorMessage": "Again some error message"
    }
  ]
```

and I'm checking jsonpath as

`($.error[1].errorMessage).is("Fixed Error Message")`

But, different API's have different error object and fixed errorMessage can be placed in the array at any index location.

How can I dynamically check whether that fixed errorMessage present in the jsonArray without worrying about arrayIndex ?

Can I make a query which independently match the string with array element without mentioning the array index, something like below?
`($.error[*].errorMessage).is("Fixed Error Message")`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can filter the array with the following:

```
JsonPath.query("$.error[?(@.errorMessage=='Fixed Error Message')]", json)
```

**EDIT 1:**

This would be preferred to check if the message was actually found:

```
jsonPath("$.error[?(@.errorMessage=='Fixed Error Message')]").exists
```

If you want to do the .is() check you can try the following (not very nice):

```
jsonPath("$.error[?(@.errorMessage=='Fixed Error Message')].errorMessage").is("Fixed Error Message")
```